# CSS/JQuery: A scrolling, overlay div and a centered layout - how to get it in a somewhat fixed position?

Tags: jquery, css, layout, html, overlay

After some searches via Google, I can't think of other keywords and am still stuck.

**Here's what I got and want to get:**
A website for which a cms is used with a centered layout (which consists of a navigation, underneath this it's divided into a main content part and a marginal column and ends with a footer) and a div I want to use as an overlay. To be precise, it is supposed to end up right over the right column and it should not vanish if the user scrolls down, but stay there on top of the marginal column. Later, there'll be some close-button added to make it hide so the actual column can be used, but that's another story.

**What I can work with to get this solved:**
JQuery, JavaScript, CSS, HTML - but with the first two I am quite unexperienced.

**What I did so far:**
-Try out with position: fixed; absolute; tried out with top/left/right/bottom and so on to make it stick there (which of course works with absolute, but it isn't staying on top then if the user scrolls)
-Search for some way to get it done with JQuery (Found the Lightbox-idea, thought of that, too, but that one changes its position with the window size, too and therefore isn't usable)
-Search for a CSS-solution (found only the fixed-stuff and how to get it done in IE, but that won't help for I got to relate it to the LAYOUT and not the WINDOW)

And when I just searched Stackoverflow specifically, I found some question that seemed similar, but only that it couldn't be done with CSS and the person would do it with JS then - but I couldn't find HOW to do it then. So.. Yeah. Help, please?

I'd provide you with the website, but since it isn't actually LAUNCHED yet, I don't think my boss would be okay with it. Sorry.

Why, yeah, here we go with that example then.

```
<div class="Content">
  <div class="InnerContent">
    Insert text of page here
  </div>

  <div class="MarginalColumn">

    Newsletter<br/>
    Contact <br/>
    Whatever <br/>

    <div class="MargOverlay">
       Here goes some random Text, random length, maybe some picture - that's variable
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

.Content{
    padding: 0 9px 80px 11px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 77px;
    width: 975px;
}

.Content .Innercontent{
    border-right: 1px solid #D9DADB;
    float: left;
    padding: 0 20px 20px;
    width: 714px;
}

.MarginalColumn{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    float: right;
    padding: 10px 0 0;
    width: 219px;
}

.MargOverlay {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 106, 178, 0.8);
    color: white;
    height: auto;
    left: 780px;
    max-height: 670px;
    padding: 5px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 220px;
    z-index: 80;
}
```

Comment: Oh, right, what I forgot: Of course I'm using z-index to make it overlay to begin with.

Comment: You need to post some code. Nobody can guess what's happening by you describing it. Try to recreate the problem using a small toy example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A combination of CSS & jQuery/JavaScript could fix this:

jQuery:

```
$('#my_overlay').css('position', 'fixed')
.css('top', ($(window).height() - $("#my_overlay").height()) / 2)
.css('left', ($(window).width() - $("#my_overlay").width()) /2)
```

You can also translate those easily to basic JavaScript, but since IE gives you the window height and width in odd ways (until IE 9 you can't use `innerHeight` and `innerWidth`), it's a bit of pain in the ass.

Also `position: fixed` has some issues in IE 4-7.  But really, IE7?  If you're trying to support IE7, I feel for you.

Comment: No, really, JQuery is just perfect. I'm gonna try that tomorrow morning and give some feedback. Window.. Why didn't I think of Window!? Thanks already.

Comment: Don't forget to upvote and accept if it works for you... (which it will since this is exactly how we handle this use case on our bookmarklet app)

Comment: Alright.. that worked out! Great! Thanks so far. Just one thing: Is there something I can do to prevent the Overlay from moving if the window is resized that far that parts of the Page vanish, too? They don't adjust to the new size but just stay in that size (it's with pixel all the time) - right now it'd be that the Marginal Column would vanish at the right side and the Overlay still exists then (as soon as the lower scrollbar is displayed, that is)

Comment: Okay, I solved it myself - I used a second DIV as some overlay-container and adjusted it with tkone's code and that worked out for me. Combined with a little positioning of the Overlay in its way larger container, it works great :3 Thanks again. And, by the way, I'd love up upvote, but it says I can only do that with 15 rep.

Comment: Sounds good!  You could also attach a javascript listener to the "resize" event and reposition the the overlay using the `top` and `left` css commands.